# How can I remove index.html from the url of my site that was deployed to Heroku?

Tags: php, .htaccess, heroku

I'd like to remove the `index.html` from the url of my site that I've deployed to Heroku. I'm doing the one line PHP hack so I can have a static site on Heroku. I tried removing it from .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

but it didn't work. Is there any other way to remove it?

Comment: What are you trying to deploy? You've tagged this question with [tag:php], but your text says you want a static site? (Note that Heroku is a poor choice for hosting a static site. It's optimized for hosting web _applications_, not static HTML.)

Comment: yeah i know but you can deploy a static site with one line of php. `<?php header( 'Location: /index.html' ) ;  ?>` I tagged php because I wasn't sure if this was causing the issue. It might not be the the best place to host this kind of site, but at least its free.

Comment: …sometimes I'm amazed at the hoops people will go through to use the wrong tool for the job. There must be other options for hosting static sites that are _much_ more appropriate and also free.

Comment: Well if you find it let me know, because I don't enjoy using Heroku at all. At this point anytime I deploy something to Heroku I just know to allot  2+ hours for debugging.

Comment: @DavidK, that's no fault of Heroku's. It's because you are _using the wrong tool_. I'm not going to search for another host for you, but I urge you to do just that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping this works, burr Like Chris Said, Heroku is a poor choice.
Anyways, Change,

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

I couldn't test Rewrite rule, Notify me if it worked.
And Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be into **dirty hacks**, if you want to rewrite the URL for a specific page, you can do it with **javascript**. Just place this at the end of your html file, before the closing `</html>` tag.

```html
<script id="urlRewriting">
var newUrl = "/";
window.history.pushState('data', 'Title', newUrl);
</script>
```

But try to avoid that while programming more professional websites... As this is **dirty developer behaviour**